# Why is this Test not pulling up the test user or account?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I've been trying to build a test class to cover a trigger that was requested recently that will change the owner of a contact to match the owner of an account.

The test cannot seem to ever find the test user or account regardless of what I do.

Here's the APEX code I have right now:

```
@isTest
public class testContactInsert{
    static testMethod void InsertAccountContact(){
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser1337@testingorg.com');

        test.startTest();

        insert u;

        List<User> testUserQuery = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Alias = 'standt' LIMIT 1];

        System.debug('Test User ID = '+ testUserQuery[0].Id);

        Account testAccount = new Account(Name = 'Contact Test Account', OwnerId = testUserQuery[0].Id);

        insert testAccount;

        List<Account> testAccountQuery = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Contact Test Account' LIMIT 1];

        System.debug('Test Account ID = ' + testAccountQuery[0].Id);

        Id testAccountId = testAccountQuery[0].Id;

        Contact testContact = new Contact(firstName = 'Test', lastName = 'Contact', AccountId = testAccountId);

        insert testContact;

        test.stopTest();

    }
    static testMethod void TestContactOwner(){
        List<Contact> testContact = [SELECT firstName, lastName, Id, OwnerId FROM Contact WHERE firstName = 'Test' AND lastName = 'Contact' LIMIT 1];

        if(!testContact.isEmpty()){
            System.debug('The following are the contacts pulled from the testContact query: ');
            for(Contact c:testContact){
                System.debug(c.firstName + ' ' + c.lastName);
            }
            System.debug('...Finished listing contacts.');
        }
        else{
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'No Contact was found!');
        }
        List<Account> testAccountQuery = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Contact Test Account' LIMIT 1];

        if(!testAccountQuery.isEmpty()){
            System.assertEquals(testContact.get(0).OwnerId, testAccountQuery.get(0).OwnerId);
        }
        else{
            System.Debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'No Account was Found!');
        }
    }
}
```

Right now the Debug Log is getting both errors at the bottom, that neither a contact or account can be found.

Comment: can you confirm that user get inserted by putting system.assernotequals(null,u.id) after insert u; statement

Comment: @Himanshu I just did that and it is being inserted with an ID

Comment: I'm pretty sure methods are private by default, what you've created in one method can't been seen by another. You're creating your Account and Contact records in testContactInsert() but not in TestContactOwner(). Try putting the create methods in with your TestContactOwner() method. Writing this as a comment purely because I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: ok, so you are saying that List<User> testUserQuery = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Alias = 'standt' LIMIT 1]; return 0 size ?

can you do following query.

ist<User> testUserQuery = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE id = :u.id]

Comment: @Poet they are two different test method and they can't access each other data in any way. @ cody, in which method you are seeing error ?

Comment: @Himanshu Yes he's creating data in one then trying to query it in another. James' answer confirmed what I thought in that test methods are private meaning they can't "see" data created in others. "By default, a method or variable is private and is visible only to the Apex code within the defining class. You must explicitly specify a method or variable as public in order for it to be available to other classes."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it matter that the user is created in a different method?  I don't think the TestContactOwner() method can access data created in InsertAccountContact() method.

Try annotating your method with "@testSetup"

https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/TestClasses

Comment: This is exactly what I thought.

Comment: Wow, I was only a few seconds behind your comment... :)

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure to be honest, but then I've always created test data in the same method as what I assert for example. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend you create a RunAs user so you have a context for this Test class to run under.

Next, you create the User who will be the User who creates the Account.

Then you create a User who will create the Contact as a Contact always has to be owned. Right now, without a RunAs User, you're not clearly assigning an owner to the contact by using OwnerId = Id of RunAsUser or User2 that you've created (the preferable method).

The code would look more like this:

```
@isTest
public class testContactInsert{
    static testMethod void InsertAccountContact(){

        User testRunner = [Select Id FROM User WHERE Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' limit 1];

        system.runAs(testRunner){

        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 

        User U0 = new User(Alias = 'standt0', Email='standarduser0@testorg.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing0', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser13370@testingorg.com');

        insert U0;

        System.debug('Test User U0 ID = '+ U0.Id);

        User U1 = new User(Alias = 'standt1', Email='standarduser1@testorg.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing1', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser13371@testingorg.com');

        insert U1;

        System.debug('Test User U1 ID = '+ U1.Id);

        Account testAccount = new Account(Name = 'Contact Test Account', OwnerId = U0.Id);

        insert testAccount;
        System.debug('Test Account ID = ' + testAccount.Id);

        Contact testContact = new Contact(firstName = 'Test', lastName = 'Contact', AccountId = testAccountId, OwnerId = U1.Id );



        test.startTest();

        insert testContact;

        test.stopTest();


        //if your trigger worked correctly the following assert should be true
        system.assertEquals(testContact.OwnerId, U0.Id

   }// end runAs    }
}
```